# Profile curvature and soil moisture correlation: issue in interpretation

Tags: curvature, correlation

I have a question related to the profile curvature values.

In an article I was reading (reference provided at the bottom of this question), scholars have found a negative correlation between profile curvature and soil moisture (articles' pages 274-75).

Now, it is my understanding that (judging from the fact that the correlation is negative) when profile curvature has negative values (i.e., convex), the moisture should be high, and viceversa.

Now, what I am wondering is how can a convex sloping terrain hold more moisture than a concave one? May be I am missing something here....

Thanks for any elucidation.

Reference:
Famiglietti, J., Rudnicki, J., & Rodell, M. (1998). Variability in surface moisture content along a hillslope transect: Rattlesnake Hill, Texas. Journal of Hydrology, 210(1-4), 259–281. doi:[10.1016/S0022-1694(98)00187-5](http://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-1694(98)00187-5)

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the publication and must state that I don't really see a correlation between soil moisture and curvature. The values in figure 8 are negative, yes. But if you look at the sparsely available days of precipitation you see the coefficients of correlation tending towards zero. My conclusion would be that there is a negative correlation for dry periods almost no correlation for rainy days. I think this is also communicated like this in the later discussion.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. But, sticking with the negative correlation during the dry periods,  my questions still stands.